# How to unit test if an image was loaded using Coil + Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, coil, android-jetpack-compose-testing

I'm loading an image using [Coil for Compose](https://coil-kt.github.io/coil/compose/) like below.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun SvgImageSample() {
    val painter = rememberAsyncImagePainter(
        model = ImageRequest.Builder(LocalContext.current)
            .decoderFactory(SvgDecoder.Factory())
            .data("https://someserver.com/SVG_image.svg")
            .size(Size.ORIGINAL)
            .build()
    )
    Image(
        painter = painter,
        modifier = Modifier.size(100.dp).testTag("myImg"),
        contentDescription = null
    )
}
```

The image is loaded properly. Now, I would like to write [a test](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/testing) to check if the image was loaded. Is there any [assertion](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/testing#assertions) *out-of-the-box* for that?

Something like this:

```kotlin
class MyTest {
    @get:Rule
    val composeTestRule = createComposeRule()

    @Test
    fun checkIfTheImageLoads() {
        composeTestRule.setContent {
            MyAppThemeTheme {
                SvgImageSample()
            }
        }
        composeTestRule.onNodeWithTag("myImg")
            .assertCoilImageIsLoaded() // <- this is what I want
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way would be to implement an EventListener and check the right events are emitted.  Will save you using testTags and semantic properties in the app code.

https://coil-kt.github.io/coil/api/coil-base/coil-base/coil/-event-listener/index.html

A quick hacky attempt, but you could wrap this in a Composable helper that does this for any block passed in.

```kotlin
@Test
fun imageLoader() {
    var success = 0
    var errors = 0

    composeTestRule.setContent {
        Coil.setImageLoader(
            ImageLoader.Builder(context)
                .eventListener(object : EventListener {
                    override fun onSuccess(
                        request: ImageRequest, 
                        result: SuccessResult
                    ) {
                        success++
                    }

                    override fun onError(
                        request: ImageRequest, 
                        result: ErrorResult
                    ) {
                        errors++
                    }
                })
                .build()
        )
        MyAppThemeTheme {
            SvgImageSample()
        }
   }
   Thread.sleep(500)
   assertThat(errors).isEqualTo(0)
   assertThat(success).isEqualTo(1)
}
```

Comment: Could you provide an example of this approach?

Comment: With this approach, I have to re-declare my UI in the test. I don't think this is good thing to do...

Comment: Sorry, that was just a bad example from me.  You can just use SvgImageSample(), I'll update. Take your pick on approaches, this will work even without modifying the composable code.

Comment: Got it! This "local provider" is deprecated, but changing to `Coil.setImageLoader`, it worked. My only concern is the case of the app is already using a custom `ImageLoader` and a `EventListener`.

Answer (score 5):

I found what I was looking for... Please let me know if anyone has a better solution.

This is what I did:

1. Add this dependency in your `build.gradle`.

```
implementation "androidx.test.espresso.idling:idling-concurrent:3.5.0-alpha07"
```

This is necessary to use the `IdlingThreadPoolExecutor` class.

2. Declare the an `IdlingThreadPool` object like below:

```kotlin
object IdlingThreadPool: IdlingThreadPoolExecutor(
    "coroutinesDispatchersThreadPool",
    Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors(),
    Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors(),
    0L,
    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
    LinkedBlockingQueue(),
    Executors.defaultThreadFactory()
)
```

I get this hint from [this issue](https://github.com/coil-kt/coil/issues/457) in the Coil github page.

3. Use the object declared above in the `ImageRequest` object.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun SvgImageSample() {
    val painter = rememberAsyncImagePainter(
        model = ImageRequest.Builder(LocalContext.current)
            .dispatcher(IdlingThreadPool.asCoroutineDispatcher()) // << here
            .decoderFactory(SvgDecoder.Factory())
            .data("https://someserver.com/SVG_image.svg")
            .size(Size.ORIGINAL)
            .build()
    )
    Image(
        painter = painter,
        modifier = Modifier
            .size(100.dp)
            .semantics {
                testTag = "myImg"
                coilAsyncPainter = painter
            },
        contentDescription = null
    )
}
```

Notice the `IdlingThreadPool` object was used in the `dispatcher` function. The other detail is `coilAsyncPainter` property which is receiving the `painter` object. It will be necessary during the test to check if the image was loaded.

4. Declare the `coilAsyncPainter` semantic property.

```kotlin
val CoilAsyncPainter = SemanticsPropertyKey<AsyncImagePainter>("CoilAsyncPainter")
var SemanticsPropertyReceiver.coilAsyncPainter by CoilAsyncPainter
```

This is what you need to do in the application code.

5. In the test code, declare a new `SemanticNodeInteration`.

```kotlin
fun SemanticsNodeInteraction.isAsyncPainterComplete(): SemanticsNodeInteraction {
    assert(
        SemanticsMatcher("Async Image is Success") { semanticsNode ->
            val painter = semanticsNode.config.getOrElseNullable(CoilAsyncPainter) { null }
            painter?.state is AsyncImagePainter.State.Success
        }
    )
    return this;
}
```

So here, basically the painter object is obtained from the semantic property and then is checked if the current state is `Success`.

6. Finally, here it is the test.

```kotlin
class MyTest {
    @get:Rule
    val composeTestRule = createComposeRule()

    @Test
    fun async_image_was_displayed() {
        composeTestRule.setContent {
            MyAppThemeTheme {
                SvgImageSample()
            }
        }
        composeTestRule.waitForIdle()
        composeTestRule.onNodeWithTag("myImg")
            .isAsyncPainterComplete()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, I have to say that the approach suggested by @nglauber worked. However, I cringed at that level of complexity for a simple test, so I tried a straight forward test and that works as well and I will keep so.

First, I loaded the image simply with AsyncImage

```
 AsyncImage(
            model = ImageRequest.Builder(LocalContext.current)
                .data(template.previewUrl)
                .crossfade(true)
                .build(),
            placeholder = painterResource(template.thumbNailResId),
            contentDescription = stringResource(R.string.template_description),
            contentScale = ContentScale.Fit,
        )
```

Then in the test, I simply checked for the node with content description is displayed like so

```
@Test
fun intialImageDisplayedTest() {
    val template = TemplateRepository.getTemplate()[0]
    composeTestRule.setContent {
        val selectedIndex = remember{ mutableStateOf(-1) }
        TemplateItem(
            selectedId = selectedIndex,
            template = template,
            onPreviewButtonClicked = {}
        )
    }
    composeTestRule.onNodeWithTag("template_${template.templateId}").assertIsDisplayed()
    composeTestRule.onNodeWithContentDescription(getImageDescriptionText()).assertIsDisplayed()
}

private fun getImageDescriptionText(): String {
    return composeTestRule.activity.resources.getString(R.string.template_description)
}
```

Again keeping it simple. I also added a matcher with a test tag. No Idling resource needed.